# Can I put multiple Loops in a Workflow?

Tags: designer-workflow, loop

I have 3 respective alerts: 1 year, 6 months, 90 days.

I set up 3 Stages. Then I set up a loop for my 90 day alert to run the loop every two min. for testing. It works. But when I try to create a loop for 6 Months, and 1 Year, it does not work.

Thoughts?

Comment: If you want the loops to run concurrently, you'll need to put them in separate workflows, and call them all from the main workflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**As a short answer :** yes you can use multiple loops in different stages and also nested loop in the main loop. but you should make sure that

- Each loop do not go in the infinite loop.
- The transition between stages is configured correctly and the workflow logic is right.

Comment: I have another question: 
So, I am trying to get SharePoint to select automatically the Stakeholder for "Send Email" ... right now  what I have to do is this:

If Variable: A is less than 100
and Variable: A is greater than 10
 If Current Item:Department Stakeholder equals PersonOne
  Email PersonOne
 Else
  If Current Item:Department Stakeholder equals PersonTwo
   Email PersonTwo
  Else ...so on

Here PersonOne and PersonTWO are manually selected by me by going into Send Email option. 
Is there a way to set this for SharePoint to select the person from the Stakeholder column?

Comment: I was able to figure out how to send email dynamically based on column value.